# Do I need an api key to get last known location in Android with Google Play Services?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I just recently started learning Android and am working on small projects to learn the essentials I need for to work on a larger project I have coming up.  I need to get the users last know location.  I went through [this tutorial,](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) and it wouldn't connect to play services.  Do I need an api key to get the last known location?  And also what is the easiest way to implement location awareness in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not to give any `API` key to fetch last known Location. `API key` is needed when integrating [`Google Maps`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) in Android app. [Android Location API using Google Play Services](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need api key for last known loacation.
You should follow these tutorial of android provided by google. Very easy and efficient [Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample)